# iPhone to iPad but different price

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store, provisioning

Hey, I would like to port iPhone app to iPad. In the App Store I registered the iPhone app as com.mycompany.appname. Do I need a new AppID (developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles) for the iPad app to push it to the App Store if I want a different price for the iPad app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making a separate iPad app or are you going to make a universal app? That is, one purchase that has the iPhone and iPad version in the same package.

If you're going to make 2 separate apps, then you need 2 IDs. If a universal, app, then you just make 2 targets, no new ID necessary.

I do recommend going the Universal route, you may get a lot of bad reviews from customers who are pissed off when they are asked for more money for the iPad version.

Comment: Do you know... can I change the price later?

Comment: Yes, you can adjust your pricing at any time.

Comment: @W is right about pissed off customer. Take a look at the New York Times app.  Different price between iPad & iPhone version.

Comment: You can change the price at any time. I've seen lots of success stories where devs make an iPhone-only app and sell it for $2.99, then add iPad support and sell it for $3.99. It's a good way to create buzz, get a lot of early adopters, and make people feel like they're saving money by buying at a cheaper rate before you add iPad support and up the price. This strategy is really only good for folks who want both versions.